# Find all the induced paths with a start vertex

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

Let $G$ be a graph and let $v$ be a vertex. Is there a polynomial algorithm for the following operation?

**Operation.** Find all the **induced paths** in $G$ with first vertex $v$.

---

**Background**

This problem is the confusion I encountered while reading the article *[Induced paths in graphs without anticomplete cycles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895623000850?via%3Dihub)*. The authors asserted that there is a polynomial algorithm to  check whether a graph contains no two non-adjacent cycles (and more generally no k non-adjacent cycles). Their algorithm is as follows:

- For each vertex $v$, find all the induced paths with first vertex $v$.
- For each induced path $P$, find all induced cycles that consist of $P$ and one extra vertex.
- Check whether any two of these cycles are disjoint and have no edges between them.

I am puzzled by the first step. If that's the case, then I think that finding the longest induced path in a graph would be possible with a polynomial algorithm.  But as far as I know, it is NP-hard. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_path

Comment: I think it is best to provide some background information on the problem and write down some of your thoughts. After all, the purpose of CS SE is to built a repository of meaningful information for future members.

Comment: @codeing_monkey Thank you. I will write it though I think  it has many words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following graph $G = (V, E)$ where:

- $V = \{v_0\}\cup \{u_1,…, u_n\}\cup \{v_1, …, v_n\}$;
- $E = \{\{v_0,u_1\}, \{v_0, v_1\}\}\cup \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\{\{u_k, u_{k+1}\}, \{u_k, v_{k+1}\}, \{v_k, u_{k+1}\}, \{v_k, v_{k+1}\}\}$.

[image]

Then the graph has more than $2^n$ induced paths from $v_0$. So there is no way to find all of them in polynomial time.

I think the paper states that there is a polynomial-time algorithm to find them if you make additionnal hypotheses on the graph (though I agree that many details are missing).

Comment: I agree. But, I am surprised that the authors claim their polynomial algorithm (to check whether a graph contains no two non-adjacent cycles (and more generally no k non-adjacent cycles)) follows from the fact that these graphs have a polynomial number of induced paths. In fact, before checking, we don't know how many induced paths a given graph has.  **Note:** The testing graph given is general.

Comment: Well that could still be true: you could enumerate all induced paths, and answer false when the number of induced paths becomes greater than $|G|^c$. However I am not an expert on the question. Perhaps you could contact the authors to ask further questions?

Comment: I agree with you. Perhaps we need to determine what c actually is before this algorithm is  implemented. I will ask the authors if they have implemented the algorithm.